# How do I restore my old WhatsApp history on another phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My Samsung Galaxy S3 phone was water-damaged and is not working at all. Unfortunately, I didn't backup my chat history.

I inserted my old SIM card and memory card into my friend's phone and downloaded WhatsApp. I linked it to my old number, but when I opened it, there were no contacts / chat history at all.

Is there any way I could get back my old WhatsApp chat history? There are some important messages there.

Comment: Can you still turn on the phone? The history is on the phone, not the SIM card.

Answer (score 2):

The backup is held on your old phone. You would need to be able to switch it on to be able to retrieve it.

If you get it switched on its simply a case of copying the whatsapp folder from the old device to the new one, opening whatsapp and allowing it to restore messages from the backup.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, guys! Sorry, for being off topic here. My phone is completely dead so there is no way i can switch it on. I didnt backup my chat history also so i guess there is no way i can get it back:(
Thank you for help, though:)

Comment: Yep, in that case I would say that you can't do anything to rescue that backup...

Comment: Note that **newer WhatsApp versions** store it in the folder `Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp` on the internal storage device. Inside, look for `Backups`, `Databases` and `Media`. Use a tool like TotalCommander to find and copy them via Wifi.

Comment: How I did it: 1. Install WhatsApp on your new phone, but dont start it yet. 2. Make sure both WhatsApp versions are the same. Run backup within WhatsApp on old phone 3. Use TotalCommander with Wifi on both phones to copy WhatsApp path above from old to new phone  4. Run WhatsApp on new phone with new SIM card 5. Fill in Welcome, Registration, Phonre Nr, Pin and confirm to restore backup. Done!